# Finding relative constructs of an XPath expression (algorithm)

Tags: xslt, xpath, xsd, schematron

I've come across an interesting requirement for which I already have my own working implementation but am trying to make sure that I've covered all the corner cases.

What I'm trying to achieve would be best described as "XPath condition delegation".

Let's say that some obscure schema language makes it possible to constrain instance elements using arbitrary XPath conditions. These conditions are converted into Schematron assertions and are then applied to the XML instance document. In order for it to work, each condition needs a context node against which the expression is tested (it's like saying: "Find me a certain element in the XML instance document and then check if the XPath condition holds true against it"). The thing is; some conditions in my schema language may be defined for virtual/abstract nodes, which never appear in instance documents (xsd:choice might be a suitable analogy here - it exists only in the language file and not in instances). So I thought, ok, let's simply delegate the condition from parent vitrual node to child nodes, that actually appear in XML instances. And it worked out great! If you only use absolute XPath location paths that is...

A hypothetical example of a schema language:

```
element smth {
    element c-enabled;
    choice c {
        assert "c-enabled = 'true'"; <!-- context node is <smth>, first instatiable ancestor -->
        element one;
        element two;
    }
    element foo;
}
```

This basically says, allow `<smth>` elements, that have a `<c-enabled>` and a `<foo>` child, and if `<c-enabled>` has a value of `'true'` also allow either a `<one>` or a `<two>` child. Example of a valid instance document:

```xml
<smth>
    <c-enabled>true</c-enabled>
    <two/>
    <foo/>
</smth>
```

So, as stated before, I decided to delegate the condition to `<one>` and `<two>`, essentially refactoring the above schema into the following at runtime:

```
element smth {
    element c-enabled;
    choice c {            
        element one {
            assert "c-enabled = 'true'"; <!-- context node is <one>, never satisfied since <one> has no <c-enabled> child -->
        }
        element two {
            assert "c-enabled = 'true'"; <!-- context node is <two>, never satisfied since <two> has no <c-enabled> child -->
        }
    }
    element foo;
}
```

This would obviously work only, if the XPath conditions were written using absolute paths. Each time `<one>` or `<two>` are encountered in the instance document, the condition is checked by using them as the initial context node (they are what `current()` returns in XSLT).

So after reading some [XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath) and creating an XPath parser using the wonderful [ANTLR4 tool](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Home) combined with [this grammar](http://blog.jwbroek.com/2010/07/antlr-grammar-for-parsing-xpath-10.html) and implementing a transformation parse tree walker, I'm now refactoring the original schema into this:

```
element smth {
    element c-enabled;
    choice c {            
        element one {
            assert "../c-enabled = 'true'"; <!-- u-huh, this is what we're after -->
        }
        element two {
            assert "../c-enabled = 'true'"; <!-- u-huh, this is what we're after -->
        }
    }
    element foo;
}
```

Note that this in only a trivial example of the XPath conditions I'm dealing with (it's not a matter of simply writing up a regex to handle it), since they are completely arbitrary, made up by whomever created the schema definition. The only thing I can be sure of about them is that they are valid XPath 1.0 expressions (base functions only, no variables).

---

### **So my question is**: as per XPath 1.0 specification, what are the places in an XPath expression where constructs that refer to the initial context node (in a relative way) may appear?

My current assumption is: any [RelativeLocationPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-RelativeLocationPath) which does not have any of the following ancestors in the parse tree: [AbsoluteLocationPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-AbsoluteLocationPath) and [Predicate](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates). If RelativeLocationPath is preceded by an AbsoluteLocationPath, then the combination forms an absolute construct. Within a predicate all paths refer to a different context node or are absolute.

I'm assuming this based on this graph I made (represents how productions get called when parsing XPath with the grammar I refer to above):
[image: Grammar graph]

---

Here are some examples of the places I need to find within XPath expressions. Basically looking for a formal definition of these (and possibly others).

```
(../area-type = 'stub') or (../area-type = 'nssa')
 ^                          ^
(../../../cacheMode != 'ipfix:immediate')
 ^
address-family='ipV4' and safi='nlri-unicast'
^                         ^
(../../../cacheMode != 'ipfix:immediate') and ((count(../ieEnterpriseNumber) = 0) or (../ieEnterpriseNumber != 29305))
 ^                                                    ^                               ^
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis sounds plausible to me at first reading, but since you're looking for corner cases a lot depends on exactly what you mean.  If you mean "where, in the syntax, do . and .. refer to the initial context item, and not to a context item set in some other way" then (assuming "set in some other way" is defined and understood in some suitable way) your characterization seems correct.  But those are not the only places where . and .. may refer to the initial context item or its parent:  consider `./.` -- both dots refer to the same node, which is the initial context item.  Or `./*/../.` -- and so on.

If I understand your idea correctly, you want to accept XPath expressions associated with a particular node, but instead of evaluating them with that node as the current node, you want to pass appropriate expressions to other nodes to evaluate with *those nodes* as the context item.

If you restrict yourself to path expressions, and your delegation is always either to the instantiation of an abstract class or to a child, then (a) the distinction between absolute and relative path expressions is easy to recognize, and (b) the necessary modification to the path expression is easy to describe (no change or add '../' to the beginning).  If you allow more general expressions -- e.g. function calls -- you are going to have to understand the expression structure and more complex adjustments.  If the user writes `local-name() = 'barracuda'` and this gets delegated for some reason to a child, then the child needs to evaluate `local-name(..) = 'barracuda'`.  (In XPath 2.0, I guess prepending ../ would work, but I think not in 1.0.)

You may also find relevant considerations in the literature on streaming evaluation of XPath expressions.

Comment: Yes, you understood what I tried to convey in my question perfectly. I'm now worried since you mentioned the `local-name()` function call might not work after I prepend it with `../` in 1.0. Are there any other base functions that might pose as problematic and you can identify? I'm not worried about the examples you mentioned first (`./.`, etc.). The second dot depends on the context of the first, so when I do `.././.` it should work as expected. Do you have any concrete instances of literature in mind since you mentioned it? And thanks for reading my question... :D